# Can You Use The Server To Bundle Files & Reduce HTTP Requests?

Tags: httprequest, server-side

If I understand HTTP requests correctly, they come from the client side and ask the server for the various resources needed to build the website. If this is true, is there a way to use server-side scripts to bundle everything the visitor needs in order to reduce HTTP requests?

- Am I misunderstanding the way HTTP requests work?
- Is there a drawback to this?

Comment: There is; the term you are looking for is "minifiers". There are minifiers for CSS and JavaScript for most all server platforms and languages.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources

Comment: the primary objective of minifier is to reduce the size of the ressource, not to bundle them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques:

- you can bundle several of your ressource in a single file, exemple, all css, javascript, etc...
- you can send multiple files in one:[http pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)
- http 1.1 reuse the connection so this reduce also the request/response time....